# How to integrate website's signup form into Mailchimp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, mailchimp

I currently have a sign up form on my website which asks users for their name, email, and asks if they want to be subscribed to our newsletter.

If they check off that they do want to be subscribed to our newsletter, I would like to add their information automatically into my Mailchimp list.

I tried this http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/host-your-own-signup-forms, but it simply overwrites my form action, making it impossible for a user to register on my website.

I assume I could do an AJAX call on form submit to then submit the Mailchimp form, but I'm wondering if there is an easier and cleaner way?

Comment: just send the data from your back end form processing script directly to mailchimp

Comment: would be most reliable way, yes